# Code Rules for Android API Usage in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Using Visual Studio for Mac, earlier developers were able to set "Android API Usage issues" as Errors during compile time, instead of causing exceptions during runtime.

#### Before

You can see it in this [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36507269/how-to-get-a-compile-time-error-instead-of-nosuchmethoderror-run-time-error-for), and here's the way it used to look:[image: Screenshot showing VS for Mac Code Rule for Android API Usage]

#### After

But as you can see in the Code Rules section now, there's no easy way to do this like before:[image: Screenshot showing VS for Mac Code Rules now]

#### Question

Do you know what I can put in the code rules text box now to get those errors?

---

#### Edit:

Code actions as requested by Dai
[image: Code Actions page 1]
[image: Code Actions page 2]
[image: Code Actions page 3]

Comment: Please show the "Code Actions" tab in your screenshot. [According to the current documentation that's where some of the rules are moved to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/refactoring?view=vsmac-2019).

Comment: @Dai here you go, I have share all the Code Actions in the list